# How to download source, modify source, recompile and build .deb package?

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, apt, suexec

I have to customize my Apache2 suExec module to ensure some special environment variables getting passed through suExec.

How to download the source code form Debian package `apache2-suexec`, modify `suexec.c` -> `safe_env_lst`, recompile and build a .deb package again to rollout on the production systems?

I tried `apt-get source apache2-suexec` but didn't found the `suexec.c` within the occurred apache2-* folder.

The altered source code should be like this:

```
static const char *const safe_env_lst[] =
{
    /* variable name starts with */
    "HTTP_",
    "SSL_",

    /* NEW: Perl debugging variables */
    "PERL5OPT=",
    "PERL5LIB=",
    "PERLDB_OPTS=",
    "DBGP_IDEKEY=",

    /* NEW: FCGI variables */
    "FCGI=",
    "FCGI_CONNECTION=",
    "FCGI_RUNTIME=",
    "FCGI_STARTTIME=",
```

draft based on: http://static.askapache.com/httpd/support/suexec.c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried `apt-get source apache2-suexec` but didn't found the
>   `suexec.c` within the occurred apache2-* folder.

On my Ubuntu 12.04:

```
# cd apache2-2.2.22/
# find . -name 'suexec.c'
./support/suexec.c
./.pc/045_suexec_log_cloexec/support/suexec.c
./.pc/058_suexec-CVE-2007-1742/support/suexec.c
```

> How to download the source code form Debian package `apache2-suexec`,
>   modify `suexec.c` -> `safe_env_lst`, recompile and build a .deb
>   package again to rollout on the production systems?

```
# apt-get build-dep apache2-suexec
# apt-get install devscripts
# debuild -i -us -uc -b
# dpkg -i ../apache2-suexec_2.2.22-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: thanks, @quanta. I give it a try, but I already searched for the file like you did... strange (maybe spelling error or special char).